# Can’t download models in gazebo gui

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I use gazebo 2.2.6 with ROS Indigo.

When I launch gazebo world I can’t see gazebo's model database. I go through this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_world&cat=build_world). In “**Insert**” tab I can see only models which I downloaded manually. Also I see the point “**Connecting to model database**” which doesn’t work. You can see on the picture. How I can activate download option?[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12258/can%E2%80%99t-download-models-in-gazebo-gui/) by [nampi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2371/nampi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It might take a long time to connect to gazebo's model database. I waited for about ten minutes and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [nampi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2371/nampi/) with karma: 1 on 2015-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0